# the css of my second <article> stops working when I add a new tag after it?

Tags: html, css

This is kind of weird, In my second article, I have 2 images, the first one is a circular shape and the other one has a border-radius except on the right side. I problem is that whenever I add a new tag after the 2nd article, the css of the second article is removed, not sure why.

HTML

```css
.section3 {
  background: #f6e7c0;
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.section3 article {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.section3 article img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.section3 article:first-child {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 65px;
}
.section3 article:first-child img:first-child {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.section3 article:first-child img:last-child {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section3">
  <article>
    <img src="images/IMG_9243.JPG" alt="">
    <img src="images/IMG_0244.JPG" alt="">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="images/IMG_9935.JPG" alt="">
    <img src="images/IMG_9479.JPG" alt="">
  </article>
  <h1>asd</h1>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mmc5qczc/

Comment: please note: the border-radius property does not require prefixing.

Comment: do you understand how `:first-child` works?

Comment: You need to remove the `article:first-child`, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mmc5qczc/1/)

Comment: Not fully, what I've tried is that you can access the first of let's say 3 similar elements.

Comment: It is because once you add the third **article**, the third **article** becomes the last one and the CSS is applied to the last article and the middle article gets left over.

Comment: Uhmm...I don't really get it, the css of the second article is removed only when I added a new tag after it(h1 tag).

Comment: That's because the `h1` becomes the `last-child`, the `last-child` CSS no longer applies to the second article. You may be confusing `last-child` with [last-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp)

Comment: So you mean to say that even though h1 is not an article it still becomes the last-child?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Like @APAD1 said I think last-of-type is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JSFiddle you have several `.section3 article:last-child` CSS which I don't see in the what you posted above. When you add a tag after the second article the second article is no longer the last child. It may be the last article of .section3 but it isn't the last child.

Comment: Wow, I've been using it wrong the whole time! So does it mean that as long as any tag is in the last position, then it becomes the last-child?

Comment: Yes, I was using it wrong at first too. Then I found out there is another one called last-of-type. By the way, last-of-type only works on nodes, it ignores class and ID names. That confused me for a little while as well.

Comment: All the answers are great but you gave me a clear answer first so I choose you.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the :last-child pseudo-class. So your selector says: "give me a article which is the last child inside an element with section3-class."

You could use `:nth-child(2)` or more specific selectors instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/xeoe330e/

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp